# Spring Batch: Only one instance of job should run

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

We are working on a spring batch and using HSQL database for in-memory job repository. We don't want to manage job execution history, so in each run we are dropping and recreating the JobRepostiory tables. Job is running fine so far without any issues.

My requirement is I would like to make sure only single instance of job is running. If the job is triggered twice it will reject the second instance.

**Job Context Configurations:**

```
<bean id="propertyUtil" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" >
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:batch.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="properties">
        <map>
            <entry key="environment" value="#{systemProperties.environment}" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="repDataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="repTransactionManager" />
    <property name="databaseType" value="hsql" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobExplorer" class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="repDataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="repDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" lazy-init="true" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:${${environment}_path}/batchcore.db;shutdown=true;" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
    <property name="minIdle" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxWait" value="10000"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="60000"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_USERS"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="false"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="false"/>
</bean>

<!-- Create meta-tables -->
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="repDataSource" >
    <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-hsqldb.sql" />
    <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>

<bean id="repTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="repDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

I tried extending **JobExecutionListenerSupport** and overriding the **beforeJob** method

```
public class JobExecutionListenerMonitor extends JobExecutionListenerSupport {

private JobExecution activeExecution;

public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    synchronized(jobExecution) {
        if(activeExecution != null && activeExecution.isRunning()) {
            jobExecution.stop();
        } else {
            activeExecution = jobExecution;
        }
    }
}

public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
      synchronized(jobExecution) {
          if(jobExecution == activeExecution) {
              activeExecution = null; 
          }
      }
}}
```

Now the problem is when I am running the second instance of the job for testing the job is failing during bean creation phase and throwing the below exception and it is not reaching to listener code.

Analyzing the exception I found the HSQL db file is locked by the first instance so when the second instance trying to create the datasource its not able to acquire the db file.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@7536ad47[file =D:\DART_Activity\2016\smrs\hsqldb\batchcore.db.lck, exists=true, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: checkHeartbeat read: 2016-06-01 11:11:25 heartbeat - read: -9445 ms.)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
at com.metlife.winweb.launcher.TriggetJob.run(TriggetJob.java:32)
at com.metlife.winweb.launcher.TriggetJob.main(TriggetJob.java:21)

Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@7536ad47[file =D:\hsqldb\batchcore.db.lck, exists=true, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: checkHeartbeat read: 2016-06-01 11:11:25 heartbeat - read: -9445 ms.
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile.newLockFileLock(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.acquireLock(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.open(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
```

Expert please help me how to solve this issue.

Comment: What mechanism are you using to launch your jobs?

Comment: The job is scheduled using UNIX script. However we have a mechanism to trigger this job from online application in case of job failure. For failure case support team would investigate the failure cause and if required they will correct the data then manually they will trigger the job from online application. In case of scheduled job I understand the job will run only once. But few cases we noticed the job is triggered twice from online application and we are not getting "JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException"

Comment: Each execution is a single instance, for every job running an ID is created and values associated with that execution (parameters, date, etc) are saved. In addition, your batch runs with HSQL DB in memory, so each running instance will be in a different database. If you run the batch against same BD, you can ask in the BeforeJob for the STATUS, and if you have any batch running (STARTING or STARTED), then you can update the batch status to STOPPING or better use 11.2 Stopping a Job Manually

Comment: Thanks @KarelMuñizPerdomo , the problem is I am creating the job table for every run (using 'jdbc:initialize-database') as I am using in memory job repository so I could face memory issues. The database initialization will happen before the 'beforeJob' method is called.

Comment: Finally added a check point in online application, if the job is running, the online application would not permit the user to submit a second request.